# Execute command on remote screen

Tags: ssh, gnu-screen, tmux

On a remote server I have multiple screens open and I use each one for different purpose.
For example the screen with the ID 'build' it is being used to compile some programs.
I can open that screen anytime, using:

```
 ssh myserver -t screen -r build
```

However, I 'd like to execute a command on that remote screen, directly from my host machine.
For example I 'd like to perform an `ls` in the remote `build` screen.
I 've tried something like:

```
 ssh myserver -t screen -r build -X ls .
```

but without any luck.

Any ideas?
Is this even possible?

Thanks!

EDIT:
my actual use case:

```
./buildSomethingOnRemoteScreen() && ./fetchTheBuiltOutputAndDoSomethingWithIt()
```

Comment: Not 100% if this will work but can you try wrapping the ls command in double quotes?

Comment: Not. still getting 'Connection to myserver closed'

Comment: Possibly a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7049252/how-to-create-a-screen-executing-given-command

Comment: If I'm reading `man screen` correctly, the `-X` option should only send a command, not reattach. Can you attach to the screen after doing that, and see if it ran the command silently?

Comment: It might do actually, but I want to know when something on remote has finished before I continue! I 've updated my question to put my actual use case.. and I think it might not be possible! Thanks though!

Answer (score 1):

I use tmux (more flexible than screen) on my server, and to executing a command directly after connecting:

```
ssh myserver -t 'tmux send-keys -t session-name "ls ./" C-m; tmux attach -t session-name '
```

You just have to make sure that there is a session running with session-name. The C-m emulates ENTER after typing in "ls ./"

Comment: I consider to move from `screen` to `tmux` or `byobu`. I will make the switch at some point in the future, and check this out!

Answer (score 1):

You can execute any script with paste command:

```
# read script into register p
ssh hostname screen -S build -X readreg p script_on_the_host
# paste contents of register p into running screen session
ssh hostname screen -S build -X paste p
```

Answer (score 0):

Example of executing a command on remote screen:

`ssh myserver -t screen -S build -X stuff "ls .\n"`

`-X` option passes screen specific commands. One such command is `stuff` which simply puts (stuffs) the given string in the input buffer of a window. If you omit the newline character the command won't be entered (same as you forgot to press enter). *Serial terminals may require `\r` instead of `\n` for the command to be entered                                  .*

When using `-X` you need to specify session name with `-S` if you have multiple running.

When using `-X` you may preselect window with `-p`. Otherwise the active one is used.

Using `readreg`/`register` and `paste` commands is viable if the command is stored in a file or a serial terminal is slow and the effect of `slowpaste` is needed.